# Express MongoDB - insert a document but before customize data through another query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

My requirement is pretty straightforward -

I want to insert a document in MongoDB database. But before I have to check if the `slug` already exists in database. Then perform an operation to rename the slug if the slug is already exists.

What I have been trying is to perform an `async await` callback to check the `slug` is already exists then insert the document.

```
mongoClient.connect(function (err, mongoClient) {
    let db = mongoClient.db("articles");

    let category_information = async (db, category_info) => {
        let slug_information = await db.collection('categories').find({slug: category_info.slug});

        slug_information.count((err, count) => {
            if (count > 0) {
                let new_slug = `${category_info.slug}_${new Date().getTime()}`;
                console.log(new_slug);
                return new_slug;
            }
            else
                return category_info.slug;
        })
    };

    let category_promise = category_information(db, category_info);

    category_promise.then(value => {
        console.log(value);
        category_info.slug = value;
    });

    db.collection('categories')
        .insertOne(category_info, (err, data) => {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            res.status(200);
            res.json('success');
        });

    mongoClient.close();
});
```

In console I get `undefined` value from `Promise`. Can you please figure out my code?

I am new in `MongoDB`. So also, do you have the solution of the problem in `MongoDB` way? I mean, can I perform these two queries within a single query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You don't need to await `find()` since it's actually the command coming after, in this case `count()` that is executing the query.
- Next I wonder where and how category_info is defined. It's missing in the code above. But I'll assume you have set it properly in your code.
- You must return something from your async function (a promise preferably). Right now you only return from the count-callback.

With async/await you should be able to:

```
const count = await slug_information.count();
if (count > 0) {
    let new_slug = `${category_info.slug}_${new Date().getTime()}`;
    console.log(new_slug);
    return new_slug;
} else {
    return category_info.slug;
}
```

Basically, if you use a callback like `(err, count)=>{..}` then you say "I won't be using promises here!", no promise will come and you have nothing to wait for.

- Next: `category_promise.then(...` this bit is async, so you cannot know that it'll resolve before you start your `insertOne(` query. Actually you can be almost sure it hasn't.

So you either chain another then:

```
category_promise.then(value => {
    console.log(value);
    return category_info.slug = value;
}).then( ()=>{ 
    db.collection('categories')
        .insertOne( ...
});
```

or just async the whole thing:

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const category_info = { slug: "abc" };

async function run(req, res, next) {
  const mongoClient = await MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017");
  let db = mongoClient.db("categories");

  // With async/await this is almost superfluous, but lets roll with it.
  let category_information = async (db, category_info) => {
    const count = await db.collection("articles")
      .find({ slug: category_info.slug })
      .count();

    if (count > 0) {
      let new_slug = `${category_info.slug}_${new Date().getTime()}`;
      console.log(new_slug);
      return new_slug;
    } else {
      return category_info.slug;
    }
  };

  category_info.slug = await category_information(db, category_info);
  // note that insertOne() does not return the inserted document.
  let data = await db.collection("categories").insertOne(category_info);

  res.status(200).json(data);

  mongoClient.close();
}

run(); // or app.get("/some-route", run);
```

This code runs, but I haven' tested every case (count and so on), so grain of salt and all that.

Comment: What an answer!!! Thank you for such an elaboration of `async await`. `category_info` is the request body data. It is working fine. Actually my problem was with the insertion of document before promise is handled for `slug` customization. Besides, I closed db client before insertion query is executed as promise executed later.